# Liberar una estructura

Tags: c

tenia una duda sobre como liberar una estructura en C.
La estructura seria la siguiente:

```
typedef struct alarma_tag {
    struct alarma_tag    *enlace;
    int                 segundos;
    time_t              tiempo;   /* segundos desde la EPOCA */
    char                mensaje[64];
    time_t              ahora;
} alarma_t;
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a liberar una lista enlazada de esa estructura?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes aclararla?

Answer (score 0):

Pues primero debes hacer un elemento con la esturctura

```
struct alarma_tag *bor;
```

Puedes agregarle a sus propiedades

y al final si no lo necesitas lo liberas

```
free(bor);
```

Comment: Esto liberará solo el nodo raíz, ya que la estructura es una lista enlazada.